# UIBarButtonItem - background image, drawInRect and setBackgroundImage - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to set the background image of a UIBarButtonItem to an image that I have successfully displayed in other places within the app but I'm getting a weird stretch that I can't seem to resolve.
At the same time I'm trying to crop the photo into a circle.

Here's my code:

```
        var profileView : UIView = self.profilePhoto.valueForKey("view") as UIView
        var profileImage = (user.valueForKey("profile_photo") as UIImage)
        var width = profileView.bounds.size.width
        var size = CGSize(width: width, height: width)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 1.0)
        UIBezierPath(roundedRect: profileView.bounds, cornerRadius: width / 2).addClip()
        profileImage.drawInRect(profileView.bounds)

        println("width: \(profileImage.size.width), height: \(profileImage.size.height)")
        // Show image without any cropping
        //self.profilePhoto.setBackgroundImage(profileImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
        self.profilePhoto.setBackgroundImage(UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(), forState: UIControlState.Normal, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

[image: Image with cropping]

[image: Stretched Image no cropping]

Comment: I'm seeing some very weird drawing artefacts in iOS 8 in the latest beta, including UIImages breaking out of their containers. Are you testing this with iOS 8? I've not started debugging my problem yet, but my code works fine on a real iPhone running iOS 7. Might be worth a quick check to see if it's an iOS 8 issue?

Comment: Nope, I ran it on iOS7 and had the exact same result. :(

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```